# Localizing Commands and CultureInfo in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently, I'm trying to create application which supports language switching at run-time. I've found one tutorial, which suggested using `Resource Dictionaries` for that purpose. Suggested approach works just fine for elements in XAML, that have their content set, for example, as follows `<Button Content="{DynamicResource MainTitle}"`.

The thing is that my `MenuItem`, which has it's `Header` set to the `Text` of `Command` bound to it, doesn't change `Header` according to `CurrentUICulture`. It remains the same, or, I should say, correct for project's default language, although I'm changing one with language switching. Same goes for `MenuItems`representing supported languages.

Here is the code I'm using.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static String prefix = "Resources/lang.";
    public static event EventHandler LanguageChanged;
    private static List<CultureInfo> m_Languages = new List<CultureInfo>();
    public static List<CultureInfo> Languages
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Languages;
        }
    }
    public static CultureInfo Language
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            if (value == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture) return;

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = value;
            ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            dictionary.Source = new Uri(String.Format(prefix+ "{0}.xaml", value.Name), UriKind.Relative);
            ResourceDictionary oldDictionary = (from d in Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                                                where d.Source != null &&
                                                d.Source.OriginalString.StartsWith(prefix)
                                                select d).First();

            if (oldDictionary != null)
            {
                int index = Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.IndexOf(oldDictionary);
                Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(oldDictionary);
                Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(index, dictionary);
            }
            else
            {
                Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
            }
            LanguageChanged(Current, new EventArgs());
        }
    } 
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.LanguageChanged += App_LanguageChanged;
        m_Languages.Clear();
        m_Languages.Add(new CultureInfo("en"));
        m_Languages.Add(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
        Language = WpfTestProject.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguage;
    }
    public void App_LanguageChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WpfTestProject.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguage = Language;
        WpfTestProject.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.LanguageChanged += LanguageChanged;
        SetLanguageMenu();
    }

    private void SetLanguageMenu()
    {
        CultureInfo currLang = App.Language;
        LangMenu.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var lang in App.Languages)
        {
            MenuItem menuLang = new MenuItem();
            Debug.WriteLine("Here is a display name: " + lang.DisplayName);
            menuLang.Header = lang.DisplayName;
            menuLang.Tag = lang;
            menuLang.IsChecked = lang.Equals(currLang);
            menuLang.Click += ChangeLanguageClick;
            LangMenu.Items.Add(menuLang);
        }
    }
    private void LanguageChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I've tried resseting LanguageMenu from here - no effect
        CultureInfo currLang = App.Language;
        foreach (MenuItem i in LangMenu.Items)
        {
            CultureInfo ci = i.Tag as CultureInfo;
            i.IsChecked = ci != null && ci.Equals(currLang);
        }
    }
    private void ChangeLanguageClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
        if (mi != null)
        {
            CultureInfo lang = mi.Tag as CultureInfo;
            if (lang != null)
            {
                App.Language = lang;
                SetLanguageMenu();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestProject"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="{DynamicResource MainTitle}" Height="600" Width="800">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Executed="NewCommand_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Executed="OpenCommand_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" Executed="SaveCommand_Executed"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.SaveAs" Executed="SaveAsCommand_Executed"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.New}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.Open}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.Save}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.SaveAs}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
    <DockPanel Name="DockPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Command.Text}"/>
        <MenuItem Name="LangMenu" Header="Languages" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**UPDATE**

**ResourceDictionary for English**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestProject.Properties"
                xmlns:v="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<v:String x:Key="MainTitle">Title</v:String>
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="WpfTestProject.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<userSettings>
    <WpfTestProject.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="DefaultLanguage" serializeAs="String">
            <value>en</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfTestProject.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Any thoughts about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Switching language while runtime might be pretty good, but can be a maintenance hell. So why go to so much trouble for this feature. How often do you switch the language?

Comment: Not so often, actually. Considering the fact, that default language is memorized for future runs, I don't think that such switching will be often in this project.
Actually, this project is only a test, but I can't get it off my mind. I understand, that I can get off with hardcoded values for commands and culture info too, but this is going to be even more clunkier.

Comment: You should use the resources files for localization anyway ...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add them to my question. It's updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is that my MenuItem, which has it's Header set to the Text of Command bound to it, doesn't change Header according to CurrentUICulture.

Of course not, why would it?

You should set the `Header` of the `MenuItem` the same way as you set the localized text for the other elements:

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Header="{DynamicResource OpenText}"/>
```

Obviously you will have to do this for your localization to work across `MenuItem` elements as well.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.
So, it seams that `Command.Text` and `CultureInfo.DisplayName` are localized only once (at startup?) and aren't affected at runtime?

Comment: Correct. There is nothing that listens for changes to these source properties. They won't be affected at all when you switch resource dictionaries.

Comment: Sure, I do. One final question - you said, that nothing is listening for changes of specified properties. So technically I can create custom commands with appropriate listeners? Actually, I have no clue what to do within them, but maybe you have any thoughts?

Comment: The way your (?) localization works is by switching resource dictionaries and use the {DynamicResource} markup extension. Any DynamicResource will be updated automatically whenever the resource is modified. Of course you need to use this approach wherever you need localization. There is kind of "automatic" localization taking place so if you don't use the {DynamicResource} and resources, there will be no updates.

Comment: Got it. Much obliged.